Vector potential in Poincaré gauge
Dear members of Physics StackExchange,
I have recently been pondering the Aharonov-Bohm-effect as it relates to an infinitely long solenoid. Let $R$ be the radius of the solenoid centered on the $z$-axis with uniform magnetic field $\vec B=B\vec e_z$ on the inside and $\vec B=0$ on the outside.
Using the homotopy operator, which is used in proving homotopy invariance of de Rham cohomology, one can derive a formula for the vector potential $\vec A$, as long as the underlying manifold is contractible (the formula below assumes a star-shaped domain w.r.t. the origin in $\mathbb R^3$):
$$
\vec A(\vec r)=-\vec r\times \int_0^1 u\, \vec B(u\vec r)\ \mathrm d u.
$$
As the inside region of the solenoid is contractible, the above formula yields a correct result for $\vec A$. I was somewhat amazed, however, that the same formula yields a correct vector potential even for the outside region, which is definitely not star-shaped nor contractible. Technically, of course, one cannot integrate along a straight line starting at the origin if said line crosses the solenoid. Is there a reason, why the above formula still seems to work in this case?
Thanks for your help and kind regards.
